# Getting an empty folder on github after push up

Tags: flutter, github

when I'm pushing my project to GitHub I found out after many tries to push that it is pushed but without the lib file which it is the whole my code's folder (https://i.stack.imgur.com/21msz.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOsQB.png)

I'm trying to find out why the lib folder did not pushed with other files even it completed pushing 100% successfully

Comment: Make sure that inside your lib folder is not included in .gitIgnore! (like .dart file )

Comment: I checked that and it is not included inside

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution :**
Make Sure You are Doing the process Right.

git init
git add folder1 
OR
git add .
git commit -m "Your message about the commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourProjectName
git push -u origin master

If this doesn't Work try this

**Second Solution :**

Simply copy that folder and gave it a new name, and then followed the exact same process.

**Third Solution :**

1. Run git ls-tree -r --name-only master on the client. If this does not show all your files, then you have not committed them yet.
2. If that shows all of your files, try doing git reset --hard master on the server to check them out.
3. If that doesn't work, run git rev-parse master on both client and server, and see if they match.